# Solving $(window).resize

Tags: jquery, browser, resize

I have a a script that on $(window).resize() needs to hide divs in a list.  However, because I'm using an older OS, my browser doesn't resize in realtime.  It instead leaves a trace where it will resize, and then open letting go, it resizes.  Thus, the script below only removes one div from the list instead of all that conflict.  How can I fix this?

jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    movePivots();
});
    function movePivots() {
        var last_pivot = $("ul li:last");
        if ($("#container").width() - $("ul").width() <= 0) {
            last_pivot.remove();
        } else {

        }
    }
```

CSS:

```css
#container 
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 450px;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#nav 
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-width: 450px;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
}

ul 
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    movePivots();
});
    function movePivots() {
        var last_pivot = $("ul li:last");
        while ($("#container").width() - $("ul").width() <= 0) {
            last_pivot.remove();
            last_pivot = $("ul li:last");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it triggers an infinite loop for me.

Comment: @Hubrid hm, actually, I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. Try changing your $("ul")-call to last_pivot instead

Comment: ahh nvm, it works!  the last line you added prevented it from infinite looping... that's weird though, I thought that last_pivot could change dynamically without me having to redefine it.  thanks though, +1 / correct answer!

Comment: No, it's not redefined. var last_pivot is the definition. What I do is to set a new value on the variable. The jQuery-expression "ul li:last" will evaluate just once, and will match the last li:s in every ul. That's instantly. Then you remove it. You'll now have a new li:last and you have to get that new one with a new jQuery-call. Beware though, this will only work if you have zero or one ul-list, not more